# KTX vs DDS images in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, dds-format

I used DDS (DXT5)till now for fast load of texture data.Now,I [read](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/tools/KTX/) that since OpenGL 4.3 (and for ES2) the compressed standard is KTX(ETC1/ETC2).I integrated the Khronos libktx SDK and bench-marked.
Updating texture using  **glCompressedTexSubImage2D**  for 3000 times the results are:

DDS:
1450 - millisecond

KTX - forever....

Actually, running a loop of only 300 times updating KTX, the total time already reaches 24 seconds!

Now I have 2 questions:

1. Is this the expected speed of KTX?
2. if the answer to the first question is "YES" then what is the advantage of ETC except of smaller file size than that of DDS?

I use OpenGL 4.3 with Quadro4000 GPU.

Comment: "*I read that since OpenGL 4.3 (and for ES2) the compressed standard is KTX(ETC1/ETC2).*" Don't believe everything you read. *Especially* if it's on the "OpenGL SDK" site. KTX is in no way a "standard".

Comment: Also, KTX is only a file format. It can hold S3TC compressed formats just fine, as well as uncompressed formats.

Comment: S3TC is what I am using. Its update is extremely slow compared to DDS DXT compressed textures I use.

Comment: If the files contain the same data, then post some code. Obviously, the problem lies in the code used to get the data, not the code that uploads it (since that's the same, right?).

Comment: Well,the code is from Khronos ktxlib...Will post it anyway

Comment: What are you trying to compare here? The speed of loading the files into memory, or the speed of loading the memory images into OpenGL? Because those are two completely different things. Also, if performance is important to you, you shouldn't be relying on some other library to do it for you. Not unless you have reason to suspect that it's optimized.

Comment: Both -speed of loading into memory and into OpenGL is important.Also I stripped off the lib from all sort of needless branching etc..It really just opens file,reads the header then data, and updates the texture.

Comment: "*speed of loading into memory and into OpenGL is important.* Which depends entirely on the quality of the library. This has nothing to do with the format. And file processing is simple enough that it's completely under your control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question on Khronos KTX forum.Here is the answer I got from the forum moderator:

> I have been told by the NVIDIA OpenGL driver team that the Quadro 4000
>   does not support ETC in hardware while it does support DXTC. This
>   means the ETC-compressed images will be decompressed by the OpenGL
>   driver in software then loaded into GPU memory while the
>   DXTC-compressed images will simply be loaded into GPU memory. I
>   believe that is the source of the performance difference you are
>   observing.

So it seems like my card's hardware  doesn't support ETC.

Comment: KTX is a container only, the actual pixel format used in a specific file may or may not be supported by a given hardware. So you really can't say any hardware supports or not KTX :)